# команда sar в ассемблер

Tags: ассемблер

здравствуйте. Хотелось бы узнать как при помощи команды sar разделить число в регистре BX на 2, или же лучше использовать div?

Comment: сдвиг вправо на 1 бит как раз делит число на 2. так что `sar eax, 1`

Comment: @Mike, человек же просил регистр BX. :)